# Using Riemann Sum for ∑$c_n\sin(n\pi x /L)$

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

I have been attempting to convert the sum, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$c_n\sin(n\pi x /L)$, to a Riemann integral from *a* = 0 to *b* = $\pi$/*L* and with *n* ranging from 1 to ∞, but am a bit confused by the fact that the '*n*' appears in the numerator, rather than in the denominator, of the angular part.

Can anyone help me to convert this to a continuous integral of the form normally associated with the Riemann integral for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$(\pi /n)\sin(i\pi  /n)$?

Having already made a number of attempts, I include my latest version in the hope that someone can comment.

Using the above information, $\Delta x_k$ = $\pi$/(*Ln*).  Since $x_k$ = *k$\pi$/(Ln*), then:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$\ c_n$sin(*n*$\pi$*x*/*L*) = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$c_n$(*Ln/$\pi$*)sin(*n*$\pi$*x*/*L*)$\pi$/(*Ln*)

Substituting $\Delta x_k$ = $\pi$/(*Ln*) and $x_k$ = *k$\pi$/(Ln*), we have:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$\ c_n$sin(*n*$\pi$*x*/*L*) = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$c_n$(*Ln/$\pi$*)sin($\pi^2$*k*/$L^2$)$\Delta x_k$.

From $x_k$ = $\pi$*k*/(*Ln*), we have $\pi$*k*/*L*=*n*$x_k$, so substituting this latter relationship into the angular part, the term on the right hand side may now simply be expressed as the integral:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$\ c_n$sin(*n*$\pi$*x*/*L*) =  $\int_0^L$$c_n$(*Ln/$\pi$*)sin(*n*$\pi$$x_k$/*L*)$dx_k$

which now becomes:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$\ c_n$sin(*n*$\pi$*x*/*L*) =  $\int_0^L$$c_n$(*Ln/$\pi$*)sin(*n*$\pi$$x$/*L*)$dx$

to which the result is:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$\ c_n$sin(*n*$\pi$*x*/*L*) = 0

for even *n*, and:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$\ c_n$sin(*n*$\pi$*x*/*L*) = 2$c_n$$L^2$/$\pi^2$

for odd *n*.

Any additional suggestions or comments on my results will be warmly welcomed.

Thank you in advance